# Finding the solution of a nonhomogeneous second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm told to find the solution of a given initial value problem.
 \begin{cases} 
      y''-2y'+y=te^t+4 \\
      y(0)=y'(0)=1  \\
   \end{cases}
So first I figure I should find the general equation of the homogeneous equation.

$$
y''-2y'+y=0 \longrightarrow \lambda^2-2\lambda+1=0\\
\lambda_{1,2}=1\\
\downarrow\\
y_{genhom}=c_1e^t+c_2te^t
$$
After finding $y_{genhom}$ I tried finding $y_p$. So I set $g(t)=te^t+4$ and since $g(t)$ is a mix between the $e^{\alpha t}$ case and the polynomial case, I set my guess to 
$$
y_p=Ae^t+\frac{B}{t}
$$
and found the first and second derivatives:
$$
y_p'=tAe^t-\frac{B}{t^2}\\
y_p''=t^2Ae^t+\frac{2B}{t^3}
$$
Then I tried putting $y_p'$ and $y_p''$ back into the original equation to solve for $A$ and $B$.
$$
\left(t^2Ae^t+\frac{2B}{t^3}\right)-2\left(tAe^t-\frac{B}{t^2}\right)+\left(Ae^t+\frac{B}{t}\right)=te^t+4\\
t^2Ae^t+\frac{2B}{t^3}-2tAe^t+\frac{2B}{t^2}+Ae^t+\frac{B}{t}=te^t+4\\
Ae^t\left(t^2-2t+1\right)+\frac{B}{t}\left(\frac{2}{t^2}+\frac{2}{t}+1\right)=te^t+4
$$

but now I'm unsure how to continue. How do I solve for A and B? Should I have used a different guess? My Wronskian  is 0 so I can't use the variation of parameters method. Also I noticed that the exponential order of $g(t)$ is 1, which matches my solution for $\lambda$, which means I should multiply $y_p$ by $t$, but I'm not sure where/when I should do this.

edit: Using @gaserdt216's guess, I get the following:
$$
y_p=At^2e^t+Bte^t+Ce^t+D\\
y_p'=At^3e^t+Bt^2e^t+Cte^t\\
y_p''=At^4e^t+Bt^3e^t+Ct^2e^t\\
$$
And then putting it back in my original equation, I get
$$
\left(At^4e^t+Bt^3e^t+Ct^2e^t\right)-2\left(At^3e^t+Bt^2e^t+Cte^t\right)+\left(At^2e^t+Bte^t+Ce^t+D\right)=te^t+4\\
At^4e^t+Bt^3e^t+Ct^2e^t-2At^3e^t-2Bt^2e^t-2Cte^t+At^2e^t+Bte^t+Ce^t+D=te^t+4
$$
Then I split up the terms by their power of $t$ and got
$$
 \begin{cases} 
A=0\\
B-2A=0\\
C-2B+A=0\\
-2C+B=1\\
C=0\\
D=4
 \end{cases}
$$
but this is clearly wrong. Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: The guess $y_p=At^2e^t+Bte^t+Ce^t+D$ should do the trick, however, this a little overkill. Give it a go anyway.

Comment: Your homogeneous solution is wrong, it should be $$y_{genhom} = c_{1} e^{t} + c_{2} t e^{t}$$

Comment: @Mattos thanks, I've update the post.

Comment: @garserdt216 I'll give it a try. Since you mentioned it's overkill, is there a method I'm overlooking?

edit: Also, how did you come up with this guess?

Comment: @EmilioGarcia You want to kill the linear dependence of your particular solution on your homogenous solution. That's why the $t^2$ is there as a factor in the first term. The next two terms are extraneous since hitting it with the linear operator in this problem will just give zero so realistically you only need the first and fourth terms I gave you

Comment: The derivatives $y'_p$ and $y''_p$ in the edit are slightly too... creative. Please review this part.

Answer (score 0):

Write 
$$y''-2y'+y=\Big(\frac{d}{dt}-1\Big)^{2}y=te^{t}+4$$
Then let $y'-y=g(t)$, so
$$g'-g=te^{t}+4$$
The integrating factor is $e^{-t}$, so the solution is 
$$g(t)=c_{1}e^{-t}+e^{t}\int({t+4e^{-t}})dt=c_{1}e^{-t}+\frac{t^{2}e^{t}}{2}-4e^{-t}$$
And
$$y'-y=c_{1}e^{-t}+\frac{t^{2}e^{t}}{2}-4e^{-t}$$
The integrating factor is the same and the solution is
$$y(t)=c_{2}e^{-t}+e^{t}\int\Big(c_{1}e^{-2t}+\frac{t^{2}}{2}-4e^{-2t}\Big)dt=$$
$$=c_{2}e^{-t}+c_{1}^{'}e^{-t}+\frac{t^{3}e^{t}}{6}+2e^{t}$$

Comment: $2c_{1}^{'}=-c_{1}$ in here.